# RGoogleAnalytics: how to optionally add query parameters?

Tags: r, google-analytics

I want to write a generic function to retrieve data from Google Analytics through RGoogleAnalytics, so that I can programmatically create different reports.

The specific dimensions, metrics, optional filters and segments etc for every report are stored in a configuration file, so that I can call my function with the according configuration file name.

For some reports, I do have to use segments and filters, for others these values are empty.

I store all these values in variables named my*, so e.g. myfilters for filters, mysegment for segments etc. and to loop over a date range on a daily basis (to reduce sampling problems) I have two runner variables for start and end date.

My natural attempt is now to call query$Init as follows:

```
query$Init(
    start.date = as.character(dateRunner),
    end.date = as.character(dateRunnerEnd),
    dimensions = mydimensions,
    metrics = mymetrics,
    max.results = mymaxresults,
    table.id = paste("ga:", myprofileId, sep=""),
    access_token = as.character(myaccess_token),
    sort = mysorting,
    segment = mysegment,
    filters = myfilters,
)
```

However, when mysorting, mysegment or myfilters is empty, they are nevertheless added to the query with an empty value, resulting in an error message

```
code : 400 Reason : Invalid value ''. Values must match the following regular expression: 'ga:.+'
```

When I debug and use query$to.uri() to look at the GET-version of the query, I consequently get

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?start-date=2014-07-01&end-date=2014-07-01&dimensions=ga%3Adate&metrics=ga%3Asessions&segment=gaid%3A%3A1ZLAUAqqRYqvub-LR5Tx2g&sort=&filters=&max-results=100&ids=ga%3A5298259&access_token=...
```

The error can only be prevented by NOT adding the parameters sort, segment and filters in the Init call at all whenever they're empty.

But how do I do that? My first attempt was

```
query$Init(start.date = as.character(dateRunner),
           end.date = as.character(dateRunnerEnd),
           dimensions = mydimensions,
           metrics = mymetrics,
           max.results = mymaxresults,
           table.id = paste("ga:", myprofileId, sep=""),
           access_token = as.character(myaccess_token),
           if (nchar(mysorting)!=0) {sort = mysorting},
           if (nchar(mysegment)!=0) {segment = mysegment},
           if (nchar(myfilters)!=0) {filters = myfilters},
)
```

However, this gives me strange effects like the mysegment variable actually added as sort variable and similar, so this whole construct seems to be wrong?

Therefore I tried to manually set these values in debug mode both directly before and directly after the Init function (with e.g. query$sort="ga:date"), but the according query$to.uri() after this operation gives me the URL with parameters from the Init call only, so the values are not set by this operation at all. It seems the only way to set these values is by actually using them in the Init function call.

So apart from creating a very complicated if-else construct, checking for every possible combination of existing parameters and thus replicating the whole Init call six times with different combination of parameters - is there a way to optionally add them outside the Init function?